# why am i not capturing Syn/Ack on my network sniffer

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, sniffer

I cant for the life of me understand why im not seeing any syn/ack on my network sniffer. I want to log new connections and their directions so i thought id capture traffic and search for Syn/ack but its not working. This is on windows, dont know if it works better on linux but it is important that I get it to work on windows.

this is basically the testcode:

Main code:

```
import socket
import struct
import binascii
import os
import logger


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_IP)
  s.bind(("192.168.1.12",0))
  s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP,socket.IP_HDRINCL,1)
  s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL,socket.RCVALL_ON)

while True:
  pkt=s.recvfrom(65535)
  unpack=logger.unpack()

  IPhead = unpack.ip_header(pkt[0][0:20])
  if IPhead["Protocol"] == 6:
    #TCP Protocol
    TCPhead = unpack.tcp_header(pkt[0][20:40])
    print (TCPhead["Tcp Flag"])
    #this is what i want to do so i can continue the program but it never enters this if.
    if TCPhead["Tcp Flag"] == 18:
```

logger.py

```
import socket
import struct
import binascii
import os

class unpack:
  def __cinit__(self):
    self.data=None

  # Tcp Header Extraction
  def tcp_header(self, data):
    storeobj=struct.unpack('!HHLLBBHHH',data)
    _source_port =storeobj[0] 
    _destination_port =storeobj[1]
    _sequence_number =storeobj[2]
    _acknowledge_number =storeobj[3]
    _offset_reserved =storeobj[4]
    _tcp_flag =storeobj[5]
    _window =storeobj[6]
    _checksum =storeobj[7]
    _urgent_pointer =storeobj[8]
    data={"Source Port":_source_port,"Destination Port":_destination_port,"Sequence Number":_sequence_number,"Acknowledge Number":_acknowledge_number,"Offset &amp; Reserved":_offset_reserved,"Tcp Flag":_tcp_flag,"Window":_window,"CheckSum":_checksum,"Urgent Pointer":_urgent_pointer}
    return data
```

Everything shows correct, (Source port, Destination port, Urgent pointer, etc. In TCP flags i get Syns(2 or 0x02) Acks (16 or 0x10) fin,Acks (17 or 0x11) and push,acks (24 or 0x18) but never syn,ack (18 or 0x12)

Why?

Edit: Running on windows 10 with python 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

after further investigation it seems no incoming packets are shown. searching further more i stumbled across another site that was trying something similar like me with same problem and found a solution. It is the windows firewall that blocks incoming packets.